# Проблема с получением ассоциативного массива из БД

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Начал работать с ООП и MVC, попал в руки один недоработанный проект, и желаю его завершить, но столкнулся вот с проблемой в одном методе.

Дело в том, что выводилось нужное кол-во записей, но информация по ним - нет.

Я стал искать проблему в методе:

```
    function action_getOwnGroupsTabContent()
{
    self::needLogin();
    $own_groups = $this->group_model->getByUserId($this->current_user['id']);
    if ($own_groups == null) {
        $this->view = new View('own_groups_tab_no_content');
    } else {
        $this->view = new View('own_groups_tab_content');
        foreach ($own_groups as $own_group) {
            $own_group_view = new View('own_groups_tab_table_item', $own_group);
            $admins = $this->group_model->getPermissionsByGroupId($own_group['id']);
            if ($admins !== null) {
                foreach ($admins as $admin) {
                    if( $admin['own_posts'] != '0' ||
                        $admin['all_posts'] != '0' ||
                        $admin['queue'] != '0' ||
                        $admin['schedule'] != '0' ||
                        $admin['posting'] != '0' ) {
                        $admin_view = new View('own_groups_tab_table_item_admin', $admin);
                        $own_group_view->addView($admin_view, 'admin');
                    }
                }
            }
            $this->view->addView($own_group_view, 'group');
        }
    }
    $this->view->render();
    die;
}
```

И в процессе обнаружил, что проблема на этом месте

```
$admins = $this->group_model->getPermissionsByGroupId($own_group['id']);
```

Дело в том, что нужен ассоциативный массив, в то время как мы получаем массив следующего вида:

```
Array ( 
[0] => 137427630 
[1] => 401075503 
[2] => 0 
[3] => http://vk.com/images/community_100.png 
[4] => Полигон 
[5] => http://vk.com/images/community_100.png 
[6] => Полигон 
 )
```

Тогда я обратился к вызываемому методу **getByUserId**, и увидел там обращение к другому методу **fetch_all**.

```
  function getByUserId($user_id)
    {
        $groups_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `groups` WHERE `user_id` = '{$user_id}'");
        if ($groups_query->num_rows == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        $groups = DB::fetch_all($groups_query);
        return $groups;
    }
```

А там уже к методу получения данных из БД:

```
public static function fetch_all($mysqli_result)
{
    if (function_exists('mysqli_fetch_all')) {
        return $mysqli_result->fetch_all();
    } else {
        $data = [];
        while ($row = $mysqli_result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

С mysqli я также работаю первый раз, но судя по документации должен возвращаться ассоциативный массив. Что, в таком случае, не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[fetch_all](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) по умолчанию возвращает нумерованный массив:

```
mixed mysqli_result::fetch_all ([ int $resulttype = MYSQLI_NUM ] )
```

Для того, чтобы возвращал ассоциативный массив, надо на вход дать константу `MYSQLI_ASSOC`:

```
 return $mysqli_result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Правда, оказалось это лишь половина бага была, я еще удивился, почему по ID тоже не вывело, метод недописан. Но дальше я уже сам. Спасибо Вам!